# Eigen: how to shallow copy different row to Map

Tags: c++, eigen

when using Eigen's Map type,can i shallow copy row data to emb_look_up?

```
void func(Eigen::MatrixXf& global_matrix, Eigen::MatrixXf* hidden_vec, std::vector<int>& row_idx) {
  Eigen::MatrixXf emb_look_up(32, 128);
  for (int i = 0; i < row_idx.size(); ++i) {
    emb_look_up.row(i) = global_matrix.row(row_idx[i]);
  }

  hidden_vec->noalias() = Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, 32>::Ones() * emb_look_up;
}
```

row_idx's value is not continuous

Comment: Is `row_idx` the same size as the number of rows in `global_matrix`?

Comment: no,  row_idx size maybe 10, global_matrix rows number maybe 10000

Comment: N.B.: `RowVector::Ones() * M` is (essentially) the same as `M.colwise().sum()`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot exactly "map" it but Eigen-3.4 can use vectors of indices for expressions, [as shown in the documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html).

```cpp
void func(Eigen::MatrixXf& global_matrix,
        Eigen::MatrixXf* hidden_vec,
        std::vector<int>& row_idx)
{
    hidden_vec->noalias() =
            Eigen::RowVectorXf::Ones(row_idx.size())
            * global_matrix(row_idx, Eigen::all);
}
```

A note regarding performance: If you can, store your `global_matrix` transposed and then take the indices per column. Since Eigen [stores its matrices column-major order](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html), this ensures more opportunities for vectorization and better cache efficiency.